# How to install pip for Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: software-installation, python3, pip

I'd like to start by pointing out that this question may seem like a duplicate, but it isn't. All the questions I saw here on Ask Ubuntu were regarding pip for Python 3 and I'm talking about Python 3.6. The steps used back then don't work for Python 3.6.

1. I got a clear Ubuntu 16.10 image from the [official docker store](https://store.docker.com/images/414e13de-f1ba-40d0-9867-08f2e5884b3f).
2. Run `apt-get update`
3. Run `apt-get install python3.6`
4. Run `apt-get install python3-pip`
5. Run `pip3 install requests bs4`
6. Run `python3.6 script.py`

Got `ModuleNotFoundError` below:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "script.py", line 6, in <module>
     import requests
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Python's and pip's I have in the machine:

```
python3
python3.5
python3.5m
python3.6
python3m
python3-config
python3.5-config
python3.5m-config
python3.6m
python3m-config  

pip
pip3
pip3.5
```

Comment: Question was [cross-posted to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42662104/4518341)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got an answer on stackoverflow.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44254088/1812319

> Let's suppose that you have a system running Ubuntu 16.04, 16.10, or
>   17.04, and you want Python 3.6 to be the default Python.
>
> If you're using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, you'll need to use a PPA:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6  # (only for 16.04 LTS)
> ```
>
> Then, run the following (this works out-of-the-box on 16.10 and
>   17.04):
>
> ```
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt install python3.6
> sudo apt install python3.6-dev
> sudo apt install python3.6-venv
> wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
> sudo python3.6 get-pip.py
> sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/python3
> sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip3
>
> # Do this only if you want python3 to be the default Python
> # instead of python2 (may be dangerous, esp. before 2020):
> # sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/python
> ```
>
> When you have completed all of the above, each of the following shell
>   commands should indicate `Python 3.6.1` (or a more recent version of
>   Python 3.6):
>
> ```
> python --version   # (this will reflect your choice, see above)
> python3 --version
> $(head -1 `which pip` | tail -c +3) --version
> $(head -1 `which pip3` | tail -c +3) --version
> ```

Comment: "No module named pip"

Comment: Try doing a `sudo apt get update` and `sudo apt get upgrade` before running the command.

Comment: Thanks for the help; much appreciated. While troubleshooting this, I got my system into a state where I'm in a login-loop, and it's looking like the easiest fix will be a reformat/reinstall.

Answer (score 58):

This answer assumes that you have `python3.6` installed. For `python3.7`, replace `3.6` with `3.7`. For `python3.8`, replace `3.6` with `3.8`, but it may also first require the `python3.8-distutils` package.

### Installation with sudo

With regard to [installing `pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/), using `curl` (instead of `wget`) avoids writing the file to disk.

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo -H python3.6
```

The `-H` flag is evidently necessary with `sudo` in order to prevent errors such as the following when installing pip for an updated python interpreter:

> The directory '/home/someuser/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory
>   is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled.
>   Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing
>   pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>
> The directory
>   '/home/someuser/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the
>   current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the
>   permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo,
>   you may want sudo's -H flag.

### Installation without sudo

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.6 - --user
```

This may sometimes give a warning such as:

> WARNING: The script wheel is installed in '/home/ubuntu/.local/bin'
>   which is not on PATH.   Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if
>   you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

### Verification

After this, `pip`, `pip3`, and `pip3.6` can all be expected to point to the same target:

```
$ (pip -V && pip3 -V && pip3.6 -V) | uniq
pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

Of course you can alternatively use `python3.6 -m pip` as well.

```
$ python3.6 -m pip -V
pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

Comment: The script seems to assume that `python3.6` has working setup-tools / easy install. For that reason it didn't work for me. I ended up using `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | python3.6 && python3.6 -m easy_install pip`

Comment: I installed `python3.6` and `python3.6-dev` from `ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6` on a Ubuntu 14.04 . I'm not sure if I simply forgot setuptools or if it broke, but it wasn't working at the time.

Comment: It doesn't falsify your answer in any way =) It's just an addition in case anybody runs into the same (hopefully uncommon) problem.

Comment: @A-B-B If I want to `pip -V` be `python 2.7` and `pip3 -V && pip3.6 -V` be `python 3.6` how can I do?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari First run `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python3.6` and then run `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python2.7`. I haven't tried it but it may work.

Comment: You can use `wget -O -` to stream the result to stdout as well: `wget -O - https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo -H python3.6`

Comment: `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo -H python3.6`  was the way to go.  Now my napalm gets installed for python3.6 instead of python3.5.

Comment: It seems like for Python 3.6 the command should be a little different as the suggested has failed to me with error: "ERROR: This script does not work on Python 3.6 The minimum supported Python version is 3.7. Please use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.6/get-pip.py instead."