# How do I use pip with Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, pip

I am trying to install Python 3.6 as per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/865569), but I seem to be having troubles. My system is the following (it's on c9.io):

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

When I follow the instructions in the answer (add deadsnakes repository, `apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install python3.6`), it seems to work, i.e I can run the command `python3.6` and the interpreter fires up.

However, when I try to use pip from inside this using `python3.6 -m pip --version`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from pip.log import logger
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/log.py", line 9, in <module>
    import colorama, pkg_resources
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 1479, in <module>
    register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
```

Googling a bit, I get this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44354166/6525260).  However, when I run the command:

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

I now get the following problem:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (18.0)
```

Uninstalling and installing python3.6 again doesn't help. I still get the same error when trying to run pip. How do I fix this?

**EDIT in responses to duplicate:**

The alleged duplicate's top answer does not seem to work for me. I ran the following command:

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python3.6
```

From there I got this result:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1604k  100 1604k    0     0  4637k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 4649k
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 20651, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 197, in main
  File "<stdin>", line 119, in bootstrap
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from setuptools.extension import Extension
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/extension.py", line 7, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 16, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1479, in <module>
    register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
```

Bear in mind that I did this with a completely new environment (i.e I first installed python, then ran get-pip.py).

What should I do?

Comment: The alleged duplicate's solution does **NOT** work in my situation. I have edited my question to show my attempts.

Comment: Did you try the [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/892343/301745) on the proposed duplicate?

Comment: @wjandrea The linked answer seems to only work on Ubuntu 16.04+; I have 14.04.

Comment: I see. Maybe it would be best to install a virtual environment for Python 3.6. See [How to set up and use a virtual python environment in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/244641/301745)

Comment: @wjandrea, well I've actually decided to use an arguably better solution instead ([pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)), which I can successfully install multiple python versions with. However, using virtualenvs and version managers is slightly irrelevant to why the ppa installation doesn't work.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah Did you ever figure this out by any chance?

Comment: @red_eight Well, I actually switched to pyenv and that worked perfectly (it's better practice anyway). However, I opened a Github [issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5695) as well and found a working solution there.